# Nuxt 3 searchContent always return empty result

Tags: nuxt.js

So I was trying to add search feature but searchContent() always return empty array. I can't figure out why this is did not work. I have my  markdown documents inside /content.

Here is some relevant packages version:

- vue 3.4.19
- nuxt 3.10.2
- nuxt/content 2.12.0

My nuxt config

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxt/ui', '@nuxt/content'],
  content: {
    experimental: {
      search: {
        indexed: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Search snippet

```js
const keywords = ref('')

const search = lodash.debounce(async () => {
    const res = await searchContent(keywords)
    console.log(res.value)
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.value`

```js
const keywords = ref('')

const search = lodash.debounce(async () => {
    const res = await searchContent(keywords.value)
    console.log(res.value)
}, 500)
```